# Unauthorized 401 error GET http://localhost:3000/users/profile 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I was trying to get user information on profile page but it is showing GET http://localhost:3000/users/profile 401 (Unauthorized). 
Please find the image on below link which i getting.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfFbP.png)
Here the code which i using in three files.

**This is auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    authToken: any;
    user: any;

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  registerUser(user){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/register', user,{headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
  }

  authenticateUser(user){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user,{headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
  }

  getProfile(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Autherization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/profile',{headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
  }

  storeUserData(token, user){
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user;
  }

  loadToken(){
    const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    this.authToken = token;
  }

  logout(){
    this.authToken = null;
    this.user = null;
    localStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

**This is profile.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    user: Object;

  constructor(
        private authService : AuthService,
        private router: Router
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
        this.user = profile.user;
    },
    err => {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
    });
  }

}
```

**This is profile.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="user">
    <h2 class="page-header" >{{user.name}}</h2>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Username: {{user.username}}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Email: {{user.email}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got output, there was small spelling mistake in authorization. now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

In getProfile function which is in auth.service.ts make these changes :

```
   `getProfile(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/profile',{headers: 
    headers})
    map(res => res.json());
   }`
```

Just change Autherization to Authorization
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
getProfile(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers = headers.append('Autherization', this.authToken);
     header = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/profile',{headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());   }
```